# How can I get TokenMismatchException when trying to submit the form?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I place a token in laravel, I am getting a token error? Thank you for your collaboration.

[image]

Comment: You need to show us the code. But this is obvious even without code, you need to add token in your form https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf

Comment: in the video he doesn't add a token

Comment: told you, nobody is going to watch video, me included.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> i added this

Comment: In addition to the correct answer you could remove csrf middleware by commenting it's class reference in $middlewaregroup in app\http\Kernel.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the reason way Jeffery's code works is because the version of Laravel doesn't have default csrf protection, so if u want to make your form works, you have to manually add :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

or create the form with the form helper:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) }}
//
{{ Form::close() }}
```

which will automatically generate the hidden input tag of csrf token